# Best way to do file transfer via SCP using python and a .pem file

Tags: python, ssh, scp

I wanna to replicate that command in python:

```
scp -i aKey.pem aFile.txt ec2-user@serverIp:folder
```

I found some examples of SCP but didn't found neither using a .pem key, and without informing the user password. How can I make this in python?

Comment: Check paramiko module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use paramiko module.

Check [here for connect function](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/client.html) in paramiko which has key_filename argument.

In paramiko module, there is SFTP command which you can use to transfer file.

[Check here for SFTP info](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/sftp.html).

Demo code will looks like below:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect(<IP Address>, username=<User Name>, key_filename=<.PEM File path)

# Setup sftp connection and transmit this script
#print "copying"
sftp = client.open_sftp()
sftp.put(<Source>, <Destination>)
sftp.close()
```

**

### OR

**

You can execute above command directly using python directly.

Please [check this link how to execute command in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).

**Demo code:**

```
from subprocess import call
cmd = 'scp -i aKey.pem aFile.txt ec2-user@serverIp:folder'
call(cmd.split())
```